# response.redirect not working on page with page_load

Tags: asp.net, postback

I have a textbox onin a masterpage which I'm using as a search box. When the user presses enter I want to redirect to an other page with the search terms in the url paramaters.

Trouble it only seems to work on pages that don't have their own page_load subs.

```
            <div id="search-bar">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" Text=""></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" style="display:none"/>
            </div>
```

IN masterpage page_load:

```
    txtSearch.Attributes.Add("onKeyDown", "do_search(this)")
```

javascript function so that when user presses enter it calls btnSearch_Click

```
    function do_search() {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            var invisibleButton = document.getElementById('<%=btnSearch.ClientID %>');
            __doPostBack(invisibleButton.name, '');
        }
    }


Protected Sub btnSearch_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
    If Trim(txtSearch.Text) <> "" Then
        Response.Redirect("viewall.aspx?q=" & txtSearch.Text, True)
    End If
End Sub
```

It only works on pages that don't have a Page_load i.e. the response.redirect doesn't fire on pages with a page_load.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, thanks for the answers above but didn't seem to work. I finally got around this via this article...it seems a mysterious problem and is browser related.

http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/response-redirect-not-working-pressing-enter-key-t2888253.html

3rd post down:

"I then tried wrapping the controls in a
Panel and set the Panel's DefaultButton and that seemed to get it
working in IE."

My page now is as follows:

```
                <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" DefaultButton="btnSearch">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" Text=""></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Style="display: none" />
                </asp:Panel>
```

...and it works! finally.

Comment: Setting the DefaultButton property simply adds javascript to the page to do a form.submit. I am glad it worked but the window.location approach must also work or I will give up drinking alcohol.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the whole going to the server and redirecting. You can simply do this:

```
function do_search() {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
          var textbox = document.getElementById('<%=txtSearch.ClientID%>');
          if(textbox!=null)
             window.location('viewall.aspx?q='+textbox.value);
        }
    }
```

Comment: yeah I tried and it's still staying on same page...unbelieveable.

Comment: If you tried that and stayed on the same page, you either have a javascript error or you are not capturing the enter key correctly. I bet is the latter. My point is that you don't need to redirect the user by posting back to the server; you can perfectly do that from the client side using window.location....

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the RaisePostBackEvent method, which is called whenever `__doPostBack` is used.

```
protected override void RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler source, string eventArgument)
{
    //call the RaisePostBack event 
    base.RaisePostBackEvent(source, eventArgument);

    if (source == btnSearch)
    {
        Response.Redirect("...");
    }
}
```